# What's the water volume of an horizontal cylinder when x<R

Tags: geometry

I have an horizontal cylinder that's filled with water, I need to get the water volume when the water level is x

Answer (score 0):

This amounts to finding the area of the segment of a circle below a certain height. A formula for this is derived here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html (you want the area $A$ of the segment). Then multiply $A$ by the length of your cylinder to obtain the volume.